# Can this query be written - what am I missing?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am feeling stupid today but I have a query that I want to write but I am sensing that it might be out of my reach.

I will try to simplify the problem just for the sake of simplicity.

I have a table like this

```
[Table A]
ID | Class | Name
0      A     Sarah
1      B     Tom
2      C     Bob
3      A     Jen
4      A     John
5      A     Jack
6      B     Name1
7      B     Jack
8      B     Bob
```

I need to get all the records (the actual records not grouped by) for all the people that share the same class, but with the following restrictions:

Only get me the records where Jen, Jack & John share the same class (only those 3 no others and no duplicates).

That means the records will come as sets of 3.

So in the above example I would get

```
3      A     Jen
4      A     John
5      A     Jack
```

So far I've gotten:

```
SELECT Class, Name, COUNT(*)
FROM TableA
GROUP BY Class, Name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

But in addition to this not working correctly, I am unable to specify that the records must have the names Jen, Jack and John and nothing else.

EDIT:
I was able to do it using inner query but it is a bit slow..If anyone knows a more optimal way please let me know:

```
SELECT ....
FROM TableA t1
join TableA  t2 on t1.class = t2.class
WHERE t1.name = 'Jen' AND t2.name = 'John'
AND t1.class IN(SELECT class FROM TableA t3 WHERE t3.name = 'Jack')))
```

I could probably have included t3 with the original query but I prefer this way for readability.

Not sure if this is the exact answer but the query I was looking for worked using this style and I tried to write the simple one using the same method for anyone stuck like I was.

Comment: The requirement is not clear - once it becomes clear, perhaps writing the query will be easier. Are you looking, in fact, for all the classes with the following properties: (1) Jen, John and Jack are all taking this class; (2) no one else is taking this class? If so, `select * from tableA where class in (select class from ... where ...)` should be in the right direction.

Comment: @mathguy - no problem - will edit the question.

Comment: In the edited form, you are no longer asking that the class only be taken by 3 students, no more, no less. (No less is clear, but you removed "no more".) And indeed, you added a row with Sarah taking class A - but the output doesn't show her. Please clarify.

Comment: It is indeed not restricted - sorry I tried to mix between my actual problem where 2 of the 3 names come just once and the 3rd can be repeated unlimited number of times and the simplified version :)..This might be a more confusing so I will edit it again to clarify that I need only 1 of each and max/min of 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're after the classes where your three people all shared the same class, even if there were other people attending, then you were pretty close with your query, except you were missing the `WHERE` clause to restrict the rows to the names that you were interested in.

Plus, seeing as you didn't want to collapse the rows (`"the actual records, not grouped by"`), then you're after an analytic `COUNT`, not an aggregate.

Therefore, what you're after would look something like:

```
WITH table_a AS (SELECT 0 ID, 'A' CLASS, 'Sarah' NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 ID, 'B' CLASS, 'Tom' NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 2 ID, 'C' CLASS, 'Bob' NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 3 ID, 'A' CLASS, 'Jen' NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 4 ID, 'A' CLASS, 'John' NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 5 ID, 'A' CLASS, 'Jack' NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 6 ID, 'B' CLASS, 'Name1' NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 7 ID, 'B' CLASS, 'Jack' NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 8 ID, 'B' CLASS, 'Bob' NAME FROM dual)
-- End of mimicking your table_a with data in it
-- See query below:
SELECT ID,
       CLASS,
       NAME
FROM   (SELECT ID,
               CLASS,
               NAME,
               COUNT(NAME) OVER (PARTITION BY CLASS) name_cnt
        FROM   table_a
        WHERE  NAME IN ('Jen', 'Jack', 'John'))
WHERE  name_cnt = 3;
```

You'll note that analytic functions don't have an equivalent `HAVING` clause that aggregate functions do, which means that you have to do the filtering in an outer query. Hopefully you can see that my query is similar to yours, though?

Comment: I suspect the OP is a student and they may not have studied analytic functions yet (which is why in a comment I suggested a subquery instead).

Comment: Actually I am a software engineer, but one who has relied on code (and linq) much more than SQL - and that's the result :)

Comment: Thanks Boneist - I will play around with your sql and let you know how it went.

Comment: @AngelicCore - then you may indeed benefit from reading about analytic functions (if you will have to work with Oracle more than once). Google for "Oracle analytic functions" - of the results returned by the search, perhaps the Oracle documentation is the best place to start. You will find examples there, too.

Comment: @Boneist
Bit of a problem with this SQL code - the way it is structured allows any combination of Jen + Jack + John. I am getting 2 Jen & 1 John and different permutations

Comment: So, make it `COUNT(distinct name)` instead, then.